# Problems with algorithm2e and \If

Tags: algorithm2e

I have tried to solve this problem following this tutorial, but with no success. I was using \If and \EndIf and now I have switched to \eIf but with no success. I'm using \; at the end of each line to avoid breaking the paragraph. What's wrong in my if?!

1. http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf
2. [Misunderstood error with algorithm2e in LateX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37142/misunderstood-error-with-algorithm2e-in-latex)

   ```
    \begin{algorithm}
    \ForAll {Partition p}
       skip1=0
       \ForAll {Edges i=(a,b)}
           skip2=0
           \ForAll {bucket in p}
               j=0 % conta i caratteri
                \ForAll{chr in bucket}
                   \eIf{ chr == a or chr == b}{
                       other2find = set(set((a,b,)) - set((chr,))) \; % give the missing element to find
                        skip1=1 \;
                        \ForAll {other char k} \;
                        \eIf{other2find \== k} {
                           unstableNumber=unstableNumber+1 \;
                            skip2=1 \;
                            break  \; % smette di cercare nei caratteri del bucket
                        \EndIf  \;
                       break  \; 
                     }
                   }{
                       j=j+1
                       }
               \EndFor         
               %\If{skip1=1} % se ho trovato almeno un nodo in un bucket, salto tutta la partizione
               %            % perche' tanto l'altro nodo sara da qualche parte ma non rendera di certo la partizione
               %            % non stabile
               %   break
               %tutto questo codice non serve perche' e incluso nel break dopo if(other2find)
           \EndFor 
       \EndFor 
       \If{skip2}
           break % non serve controllare tutti gli archi per sapere che una partizione non e' stabile
       \EndIf
    \If{!skip2}
       stablePartition.append(p)
       skip2=0
    \EndIf 
    \EndFor
    \end{algorithm}
   ```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please do ***not*** format code as a quotation. It makes it impossible to cut-paste-use.

Comment: In any case, please complete your code either to make it compile (if possible) or to show the error you are having when trying to compile. That is much more useful than a mere fragment of code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be mixing your syntax between what is provided by [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) and that of [`algorithmicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx). The latter uses a `\For{..} ... \EndFor` and `\If{..} ... \EndIf` construction while the former uses `\For{..}{...}` and `\If{..}{...}` construction together with a `\;` line-terminating macro.

Here's an `algorithm2e` implementation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,algorithm2e}
\newcommand{\var}{\texttt}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \ForAll {Partition p}{%
    $\var{skip1} = 0$\;
    \ForAll {\text{edges} $i = (a,b)$}{%
      $\var{skip2} = 0$\;
      \ForAll {\text{bucket in $p$}}{%
        $j = 0$ % conta i caratteri
        \ForAll{\text{\var{chr} in bucket}}{%
          \eIf{\text{$\var{chr} = a$ or $\var{chr} = b$}}{
            $\var{other2find} = set(set((a,b,)) - set((chr,)))$\; % give the missing element to find
            $\var{skip1} = 1$\;
            \ForAll {\text{other char $k$}}{%
              \If{$\var{other2find} = k$}{%
                $\var{unstableNumber} = \var{unstableNumber} + 1$\;
                $\var{skip2} = 1$\;
                break\; % smette di cercare nei caratteri del bucket
              }
              break\;
            }
          }{
            $j = j + 1$\;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    \If{\var{skip2}}{%
      break\; % non serve controllare tutti gli archi per sapere che una partizione non e' stabile
    }
    \If{not \var{skip2}}{%
      stablePartition.append(p)\;
      $\var{skip2} = 0$\;
    }
  }
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Note that it would be advisable to define a macro for your variable definitions (like `skip1`, `skip2`, `chr`, ...) that you can use throughout your algorithms. You may want to do the same for function calls, or use `\call`. See the [`algorithm2e` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf) for many more options/details.